# Custom preview images using FileReader js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, preview

I need to **create custom preview the selected images**. I have seen several answers about doing this and they do it by creating an img element and using appendTo to place them in a specific div. I have done this successfully as shown below in a jquery "change event"

```
 $(document).on("change", "#file", function() {
    var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
    var imgPreview = $("#img-preview");

    for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = function (e) {
         $("<img />", {
              "src": e.target.result,
              "class": "img-thumbnail"
         }).appendTo(imgPreview);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
  }
});
```

The **problem** I have is to preview the images with the following **structure**:

[image]

Here the custom structure with bootstrap

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="wraper-foto-grande d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" src="img1.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="wrapper-thumb d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" src="img2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div  class="wrapper-thumb d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" src="img3.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="wrapper-thumb d-flex justify-content-center">
                <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" src="img4.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to create an array with the **target.result** to later use it in a function and create the structure mentioned above but I have **the problem that the created array is empty**. I have also seen several answers on this topic but I have not succeeded in creating the preview.

Here code:

```
$(document).on("change", "#file", function() {
  var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
  var imgPreview = $("#img-preview");
  var imagesArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
          imagesArray.push(e.target.result);
      }
     reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
  }
  console.log(imagesArray.length); //show 0
  console.log(imagesArray); // guess select 4 images, show 4 elements inside but I cannot access
});
```

My idea was to use **imagesArray in a function** to create the **custom structure with bootstrap** but I don't have access to any element.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `URL.createObjectURL` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st: Check if more than 1 images selected then conditionally set [col-**`12`**] class for first preview and rest of set [col-**`4`**] class & before image append in result `div(#imageResults)` should be empty like `$('#imageResults').html('');`.

2nd:
Check `inline condition` like `i==0?'12':'4'`.

***Note:*** I added `border` class in image parent div for testing purpose only.

```js
$(document).on("change", "#file", function() {
  var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
  //Result div empty before appending new selected image 
  $('#imageResults').html(''); 
  for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
    //`const columnSet` for full col-12 or col-4 class
    const columnSet = (i==0?'12':'4');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      // Append image preview divs
      $('#imageResults').append(`<div class="mb-3 col-`+columnSet+`">
        <div class="border d-flex justify-content-center">
          <img class="img-fluid d-flex align-items-center" src="`+e.target.result+`">
        </div>
      </div>`);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container my-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <label class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple">
          <span class="custom-file-label">Choose multiple image</span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Image Preview Area -->
  <div class="row" id="imageResults">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Raeesh Alam :D! It works like I want

Comment: :) So I would like to say that mark as correct answer.